# Replace multiple fragments at the same time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` with a navigation drawer. I have used fragments for this and when I'm moving to different menus in the drawer I add them to the backstack with `addToBackStack()` method. Basically, `Activity` starts with **Fragment A** then if I go to **Fragment B** or **Fragment C** I can press back and go back to **Fragment A**.

But now I have a notification which should open the `Activity` with **Fragment B** open and when I press back it should take me back to **Fragment A**. Is there a way to handle this like in `startActivities`.

Here is the code for the `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layoutContent, new FragmentA()).commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonA:
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

            break;

        case R.id.buttonB:
            transactFragment(new FragmentB());

            break;
        ...
     }
 }

private void transactFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layoutContent, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName()).commit();
}
```

Comment: Just make two transactions and then commit.

Comment: @toshkinl Yeah, I tried that but it creates an animation which looks weird. I kind of want to do it like it says [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) except with fragments.

Comment: You can always remove the animations.
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(0, 0);

Comment: @toshkinl I can't use this as starting the fragment and not displaying it causes some problems. Instead I used what Sipty mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just define the fragments with tags and call them as you need to?

Here's a sample of how I work with my fragments:

Start your fragments in the `Activity`'s  `onCreate()` method, like so:

```
/** Load screen1 */
    Instructions screen1 = new Instructions();
    screen1.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            add(com.example.tool.R.id.
                    instructions_container, screen1, "screen1").
            addToBackStack(null).
            commit();
```

Then you can grab them and show/hide them as much as you like:

```
/** screen 1 */
public void showInstructions()
{
    // show screen 1
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("screen1").
            getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

In my project, we use a global enum to check which fragment is currently up, so we don't have to rely on the stack, which has more than once proven itself to be unreliable.

`onBack` calls a switch, which checks this enum and acts accordingly. For your use-case, you can just track when this notification has been called, so it will go from Fragment B, to Fragment A.

Comment: The actual transactions aren't the problem. Its when I open it with a notification I need to be able to press back to go to the other `Fragment`. Something like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) but with fragments.

Comment: Think I omitted an important part of my sample code: in my project, we use a global enum to check which fragment is currently up, so we don't have to rely on the stack, which has more than once proven itself to be unreliable. onBack just calls a switch, which checks this enum and acts accordingly. For your use-case, you can just track when this notification has been called, so it will go from Fragment B, to Fragment A. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need its not ideal but it works. Can you update your answer so I can mark it as correct.